# High CPU usage with Laravel Eloquent filtering

Tags: php, eloquent, filtering, cpu-usage

I need to pick out all the teams that a user is currently rostered in, and this is my Eloquent code for it:

```
$teams = Team::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()->filter(function($team) use ($user)
{
    return $team->inTeam($user);
});
```

The rosters for the teams are arrays of user IDs, stored as a string in the database.

This is the inTeam function:

```
public function inTeam($user)
{
    $id = $user->id;
    $players = $this->getPlayers();

    foreach ($players as $p)
    {
        if (is_null($p)) continue;
        if ($p == $id) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

My server CPU usage spikes to about 60%+ on apache2 and about 30% on mysqld whenever a page with this code is loaded and I cannot figure out why. Using `filter()` on the Team model is the cleanest way I've found of doing what I need and its just causing issues, even bringing the site to a halt when enough users load the page.

Is there any way I can optimize the filtering or do I need to restructure the way my database holds the roster information?

Edit: I've updated my code to use FIND_IN_SET and managed to bring the CPU time down to 5s from 8s. Still not ideal, however.

```
$teams = Team::orderBy('id', 'desc')->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET(" . $user->id . ", players_list)")->get();
```

I have no idea how I'd go about normalizing my db for this, as the `players_list` column has a different length according to the `Event` the `Team` is tied to, hence the comma separated strings.

Comment: This is bad as you can see. Normalize your db and do it there instead. For now, use `find_in_set` - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set it will do the job with `1,5,10` strings. Also read this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898953/how-to-mimic-eloquent-relationship-with-comma-separated-ids

Comment: I've updated my post to reflect the switch to `FIND_IN_SET` which has helped a little. I have no idea how I'd go about normalizing my db for this, as the `players_list` column has a different length according to the `Event` the `Team` is tied to, hence the comma separated strings.

Comment: Is your column you are doing a FIND_IN_SET is an index ?

Comment: @Kairu simply create a pivot table for your m-m relation between `teams` and `players` - this is how you handle many-to-many relation in normal form, not comma separated ids.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering mean that you retrieve all datas from MySQL and then searching into a big array containing the result.

For large datasets, i recommand using SQL condition instead php-side filtering.

Please, post more about your database if you want a working snippet. Otherwize, check documentation for where / whereIn, etc : http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#basic-usage

Comment: I would use SQL condition checking, however the roster list is saved as a string/array of user IDs like so: `421,918,48`, and if I were to check if user ID "21" was in that roster, it would return true because of "4**21**".

Comment: As Jarek Tkaczyk said before. Storing ID in string is not efficient for query speed. It require the db engine to parse string, search into the string etc ... Maybe you should split the string into a pivot table.