# Laravel 5 HasMany whithout id relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Can I run a `hasMany` query ignoring the id to id relation ?

Example :

I have `Table A` with field id, reference(varchar), `Table B` with `id, details(varchar)`.

`A.reference` is possibly contained in `B.details` which data is stored as (string a, string b, string c).

Can I perform the equivalent to `$this->hasMany('\TableB')->select('id','details')->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(reference, details)');` as `hasMany` relation ?

(I know I can do it with pseudo relation as $this->details = TableB->getDetails() kind of function, but would like to do it more straight way ).

Comment: You could try `$this->hasMany('App\ModelName', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');` on the model but I don't think joins based on varchars will perform very well.

Comment: I tried this but it the hasMany query still adds "where in" and looks for id relation. The way would eventually be a sub query but couldn't figure it out by now...

Comment: You can, kinda: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27900746/784588