# Laravel : Explode array with relation belongsTo to model

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to explode array value and have successfully doing so by using this code :

```
@foreach(explode('.', $comment->topic_id) as $topic)
    {{ $topic }}
@endforeach
```

This is the output

```
Topic : 1,2
```

The problem is, I want to implement relation belongsTo to the `topic_id`. When I add the relation and run the code, unfortunately only one of the value is shown.

```
@foreach(explode('.', $comment->getTopic->topic) as $topic)
    {{ $topic }}
@endforeach
```

This is my model

```
public function getTopic()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Topic', 'topic_id', 'id');
}
```

Output :

```
Topic : Laravel
```

What is the right way to call this array? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: your relationship is wrong, as your `topic_id` is comma separated value but you are making relationship with id!! May be you should change your db structure, try to learn normalization for better understanding

Comment: Take a look at the answer I posted under a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386065/4848587

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `relationship` in this case. If you simply looking for `solution` then you could do something like the following:

```
<?php $topic_ids = explode('.', $comment->topic_id);
      $topics = App\Topic::whereIn(id, $topic_ids)->get();
?>

@foreach($topics as $topic)
{{ $topic }}
@endforeach
```

BTW you should `structure` your `database` more efficiently.

Comment: May i know how should I structure my database and the right of of doing this? @Sohel0415

Answer (score 0):

```
 @foreach(explode(',', $item->chapter_id) as $layer)
                            <?php
                                $chapters = DB::table('topic_types')->where('id', $layer)->get();
                             ?>
                                @foreach ($chapters as $ch)
                                    {{$ch->name}} <br>
                                @endforeach
                            @endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.