# Laravel Eloquent Relationship with a comma separated field

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many

I have inherited a DB with 2 tables I need to link, a `users` table and a `us_states` table. The `users` table has a field called `states_visited` and it's a comma-separated field (for instance, New York, Alabama and Texas would be stored as `8, 2, 41`). I want to define a `hasMany` relationship, but unfortunately `find_in_set(states.id, users.states_visited)` does not work since Laravel queries both tables separately so they don't "see" each other during the Query.

Any help resolving this would be amazing.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I posted under a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386065/4848587

Answer (score 2):

I have created custom relationship constraints to solve this.

[My First Package](https://packagist.org/packages/ghanuz/relations) | [ReadMe](https://github.com/ghanu119/findinset_relation/blob/master/README.md)

OR you can also add this package by using,

`composer require ghanuz/relations`

I have tested only with select clause not with insert/update using associates functionality.

But it can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Laravel relationships you will have to refactor to use a [Many to Many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). Your other option is to use MySQL find_in_set function but then to write your own logic for it.